# Deserializing a list of interfaces with a custom JsonConverter?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a `List<ISomething>` in a json file and I can't find an easy way to 
deserialize it without using `TypeNameHandling.All` 
(which I don't want / can't use because the JSON files are hand-written).

Is there a way to apply the attribute `[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]` to members 
of the list instead to the list?

```
{
    "Size": { "Width": 100, "Height": 50 },
    "Shapes": [
        { "Width": 10, "Height": 10 },
        { "Path": "foo.bar" },
        { "Width": 5, "Height": 2.5 },
        { "Width": 4, "Height": 3 },
    ]
}
```

In this case, `Shapes` is a `List<IShape>` where `IShape` is an interface with these two implementors:
`ShapeRect` and `ShapeDxf`.

I've already created a JsonConverter subclass which loads the item as a JObject and then checks which real class to load given the presence or not of the property `Path`:

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);

bool isCustom = jsonObject
    .Properties()
    .Any(x => x.Name == "Path");

IShape sh;
if(isCustom)
{
    sh = new ShapeDxf();
}
else
{
    sh = new ShapeRect();
}

serializer.Populate(jsonObject.CreateReader(), sh);
return sh;
```

How can I apply this JsonConverter to a list?

Thanks.

Comment: [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterType`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm)

Comment: @kiziu thanks a lot! I couldn't find it on google... :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your class, you can mark your list with a [`JsonProperty`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Properties_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute and specify your converter with the [`ItemConverterType`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) parameter:

```
class Foo
{
    public Size Size { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(MyConverter))]        
    public List<IShape> Shapes { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass an instance of your converter to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, assuming you have implemented `CanConvert` such that it returns true when `objectType == typeof(IShape)`.  Json.Net will then apply the converter to the items of the list.