# c# JsonConverter deserialize Json containing Polymorphic Object

Tags: c#, json, polymorphism, deserialization, jsonconverter

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am trying to deserialize a JSON that has a polymorphic object. Here is my basic classes and set up

```
public class Information
{
    [JsonConverter(typeOf(AccountConverter)]
    public list<BaseAccount> Accounts {get; set;}
    public decimal TotalBalance {get; set;}
    ...
}

public class BaseAccount
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public virtual AccountType Type { get;} //enum value that I base account type off of.
   ...
}

// I have a few different kinds of accounts but here is an example of one
public class BankAccount: BaseAccount
{
   public decimal value {get; set;}
   public override AccountType Type { get {return AccountType.Bank}
   ...
}
```

In my AccountConverter.cs I created a ReadJson method like so

```
    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var jo = JObject.Load(reader);
    var account= jo.ToObject<BaseAccount>();
    if (account== null) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    return account.Type switch
    {
        AccountType.Bank => jo.ToObject(typeof(BankAccount), serializer),
        ... // have multiple other account types
        _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
    };
}
```

I call my deserializeObject in my response method like

```
JsonConvert.DerserializeObject<Information>(result, JsonConverterSettings.Settings)
```

I keep on getting errors on the first line in the ReadJson method. "Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object. StartArray. Path...."

Am I even going about this in the right way??

Comment: Please add json example.

Comment: But error say you get array, not `JObject` in reader, mb `JArray.Load(reader)`

Comment: Take a look at the converter from [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182),it does what you want.

Comment: Oh I see you need to use `[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeOf(AccountConverter)]` instead of `[JsonConverter(typeOf(AccountConverter)]` because your converter applies to the list items, not the list itself.  See [Deserializing a list of interfaces with a custom JsonConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40979963/3744182). In fact this looks to be a duplicate, agree?

Comment: @dbc the [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeOf(AccountConverter)] got the Json to  deserialize with no errors. I can see the Json Keys now in my object. Only weird thing is the values for them are all coming back as null. But thats a different issue and it seems this issue is solved. Thank you