# Do I need a separate custom JsonConverter for an object and an array of that object?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonconverter

I'm importing Json from a file.  Let's say it looks like this

```
{
    "name": "Test System",
    "devices": [
        {
            "type": "Touchpanel",
            "name": "Main Touchpanel",
            "id": "1",
            "model": "TS-1070"
        },
        {
            "type": "Display",
            "name": "Front Display",
            "id": "2",
            "hasscreen": false
        }
    ]
}
```

The class I'm importing to looks like this

```
class ConfigData
{
    [JsonProperty("devices")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ConfigConverter))]
    public IConfig[] Devices { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ConfigConverter is a custom JsonConverter that checks "type" and figures out what implementation of IConfig the device should be.  This works perfectly if I'm only deserializing a single Device, but as soon as I move to an array of devices, the converter gives me an error.  Obviously an array of devices is not deserialized the same as a single device.

Is there a native way to say "For each device in this array, use this converter"?  Or do I have to make a separate custom converter that handles an array of devices.  I'd prefer not to have essentially the same code in multiple customer converters.

The ReadJson in ConfigConverter looks like this

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
    var config = default(IConfig);
    switch (jsonObject["type"].Value<string>().ToLower())
    {
        case "display":
        config = new DisplayConfig();
        break;
        case "touchpanel":
        config = new TouchpanelConfig();
        break;
    }
    serializer.Populate(jsonObject.CreateReader(), config);
    return config;
}
```

This works with a single object and doesn't work with an array.  I can envision ways to rewrite it so that it works with an array, but all of those would cause it to stop working with a single object.  Looking for the cleanest and most elegant solution that lets me have a single converter that works on both a single object and an array of that object.

Comment: If you have access to the definition of `IConfig`, try placing the attribute: `[JsonConverter(typeof(ConfigConverter))]` on the interface instead of the `ConfigData.Devices` property.

Comment: `type` is just a property.  you dont need a custom converter for that

Comment: Use `[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(ConfigConverter))]` to apply a converter to collection items.  See: [Custom json serialization for each item in IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36580520/3744182) and [Deserializing a list of interfaces with a custom JsonConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40979963/3744182), of which this looks to be a duplicate.

Comment: @jimnkey That worked perfectly, sorry I never got back here to reply after it was closed.  I was so focused on the bigger picture I didn't think to go further up the chain.